# Decoding font with a given codepage

Tags: python, decoding, codepages, afp

If given a set of text "abcdefg-foo" that is encoded with codepage "xzc" is it possible in python to decode those characters with the codepage?

More specifically, we have a known AFP codepage T1V10500. The font we extract is being extracted from an AFP that references this codepage. We can extract the reference and build the path to the codepage.

```
codepage="/path/to/codepage/T1V10500"
ascii_encoded_extracted_afp_text=extract_afp_text().decode(codepage).encode("ascii")
```

This is an oversimplification of what I wish to achieve, but I hope to understand if the concept is available in python specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/)

There seems to be a python binding ([http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU/0.8.1)](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU/0.8.1)

If the codepage used in your AFP file is generic (and not a custom one) you can easily build a converter with ICU from the codepage specified encoding (T1v10500 should be CP500 ie. IBM EBCDIC International) to ascii or whatever encoding you need.
ICU is a great library and is used in most of IBM AFP files tools.

If you find ICU too cumbersome and do not need to handle other codepages you can build a simple conversion table from CP500 to ASCII